# Как получить свойство ItemSource внутри колонки, внутри стиля, внутри дата триггера?

Tags: wpf, xaml

Нужно получить свойство FilePath и проверить не null'ли оно!

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ссылка">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock>
                <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.GetHyperLinkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Filepath}" Content="{Binding Filepath}" 
                    Style="{StaticResource HyperlinkStyledButton }"/>
                <TextBlock.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Filepath, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=PreviousData}}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </TextBlock.Style>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Много странного, давайте так

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn Header="Ссылка">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Button Command="{Binding DataContext.GetHyperLinkCommand, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" CommandParameter="{Binding Filepath}" Content="{Binding Filepath}">
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button" BasedOn="{StaticResource HyperlinkStyledButton}">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Filepath}" Value="{x:Null}">
                                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                            </DataTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Здесь вы привязываете `Content="{Binding Filepath}"`, точно так же и в тригере привязка работает.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно странно. Почему студия в подсказках свойства не выводит тогда? Именно если так делать.

Comment: @yava43 чтобы выводила, надо `<DataTemplate DataType="...">` указывать явно. Или `d:DataType` чисто для XAML дизайнера. Точно не вспомню, поробуйте.